# DateBox/datepicker in smartGwt

Tags: datepicker, smartgwt, datechooser

I want to add a datebox similar to the one in give link
http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=DateBox&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=
in my web aplication project(smartgwt).

In short I want the datebox(jquery) equivalent in smartGwt.
when i googled i found out there is something called dateChooser in smartGwt but it works like a calendar i want something like the one in above link textfield with a button which on clicking displays the calendar and the selected date appears on the textbox.

please give any suggestions i am using smartGwt LGPL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a DateItem with useTextField=true to get the required behavior.

```
DateItem dateItem2 = new DateItem();  
dateItem2.setTitle("Date");  
dateItem2.setUseTextField(true);  
dateItem2.setHint("<nobr>Direct date input</nobr>");
```

Check 'Date Controls' section in http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#form_controls_various.

DateItem is a FormItem, meaning you need to put it in a form, and will work just like other form controls.

[DateChooser](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#controls_category_datechooser) on the other hand is a standalone widget that you can embed among other widgets on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen such a component in smartgwt showcase but there is something called `PickerIcon` which can be coupled to a `TextItem` to achieve what you want.

```
PickerIcon datePicker = new PickerIcon(PickerIcon.DATE, new FormItemClickHandler() {  
    public void onFormItemClick(FormItemIconClickEvent event) {  
        SC.say("Date Picker clicked");  // or show a dateChooser component
    }  
});

TextItem datePickerControl = new TextItem("datePicker", "Date Picker");  
datePickerControl.setIcons(datePicker);
```

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#form_category_picker_icons

Hope this can help !